# Github Workflow: How to map input option to value

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following input set up for my Github Workflow

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: choice
        description: Environment
        options:
          - Development
          - QA
          - UAT
          - Production
```

If the user picks `Development` as the environment, I want to use the word `dev` in some of my string concatenations, if they pick `Production` I want to use `prod` for the same purpose.

Here's an example of what the areas look like where substitution needs to occur.

```
- name: Package App
  run: |
    move-file .env.$TARGET_ENVIRONMET .env
    yarn package:$TARGET_ENVIRONMENT
```

In this example I need the `move-file` command to be `move-file .env.dev .env` and the `yarn package` command to be `yarn package:dev` for Development but I'm having trouble mapping `Development` to dev. I looked at setting a variable to `dev` if the user picked `Development` but it looks like the only variable support is for setting environment variables and that doesn't appear to be possible conditionally.

So I can't do something like this

```
env:
  if: inputs.environment == 'Development'
    TARGET_ENVIRONMENT: 'dev'
  if: inputs.environment == 'Production'
    TARGET_ENVIRONMENT: 'prod'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some ways to map your input to env variable - you can either use an action that does just that:

```yaml
- uses: kanga333/variable-mapper@master
  id: export
  with:
    key: "${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}"
    map: |
      {
        "Development": {
          "environment": "dev"
        },
        "Production": {
          "environment": "prod"
        }
      }
    export_to: env
- run: |
    move-file .env.$environment .env
```

or you can use kind of hack and define your env (on job level) like this:

```yaml
env:
  TARGET_ENVIRONMET: >
    ${{ fromJson('{
      "Development": "dev",
      "Production": "prod"
    }')[github.event.inputs.environment] }}
steps:
  - run: |
      move-file .env.$TARGET_ENVIRONMET .env
```

Comment: how is it possible to add secrets for the values? 
i tried it with ${{ secrets.FOO }} but that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Bash users will be familiar with the short-circuit syntax:

```yaml
steps:
  - run: |
      move-file .env.${{ ($inputs.environment == 'Development') && 'dev' || 'prod' }} .env
```